# Update OpenLayers popup

Tags: popup, openlayers, marker

I am trying to update some popups in my map but I am not able to do that.

Firstly I create some markers, and with the next code, I create a popup associated to them. One popup for each marker:

```
 popFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature(markers, location); 
                         popFeature.closeBox = true;
                         popFeature.popupClass =     OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud, {
                                 'autoSize': true
                         });
                         popFeature.data.popupContentHTML = "hello";                         
popFeature.data.overflow = (false) ? "auto" : "hidden";     
                         var markerClick = function (evt) {
                                if (this.popup == null) {
                                    this.popup = this.createPopup(this.closeBox);
                                    map.addPopup(this.popup);
                                    this.popup.show();
                                } else {
                                    this.popup.toggle();
                                }
                                currentPopup = this.popup;
                                OpenLayers.Event.stop(evt);
                         };
                         mark.events.register("mousedown",     popFeature, markerClick);
```

After that, I add the new marker to my marker layer.

Everything is fine until here, but, I want to update the popupcontentHTML some time later and I don't know how I can access to that value.

I read OL API but I don't understand how to get it. I am lost about features, events, extensions...

I want to know if I can access to that property and write other word.

Answer (score 5):

I answer myself, maybe it helps other people in future:

```
for(i = 0; i < map.popups.length; i++){
if(map.popups[i].lonlat.lon == marker.lonlat.lon){
map.popups[i].setContentHTML("new content");
}
}
```

Content will be refreshed at the moment.